# C# & EF Core 6 : how to prevent included property (which is a view) from being updated?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, orm, ef-core-6.0

When I use the `.Update` function for my object, it cascades and updates all of its included related entities, which is expected.
However, one of the entities (two layers down) is included from a view. I don't want this to be updated, I only have the view configured as a relationship so I can query that related data.

Because of this, I end up getting the following error:

> SqlException: Update or insert of view or function '...' failed because it contains a derived or constant field (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn6Lj.png)

I have the DbSet configured as a view (using Fluent API `ToView("...").HasKey(m => m.Id)`)

I tried configuring all of my properties to have the `SaveBehavior` of `Ignore`, and although tedious, I expected it to just not attempt to update the view at all. However, even then, I still got the same exact `SqlException` error as shown above.

Comment: A view can still be used like a table in some cases, which can be useful for backwards compatibility when making schema changes. I think you're looking for the 'NoChangeTracking' option

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I'm sure that's useful in many cases, but in this particular case, I don't want it to behave like a table. When using `NoChangeTracking`, how do I make that apply only to a View, call it `Bar`, when I use a statement like `context.Include(m => m.Foo).ThenInclude(m => m.Bar)`? I still want everything else updated, just not the properties in `Bar`.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to configure this for a DbSet. It's easy to do for the whole context, and for a specific query. What happens if you set the navigation property to `null`? I seem to recall EF _adds_ entities when you load the object graph, but doesn't remove orphaned entities unless they are in the change tracker too

Comment: You could try just setting the updated properties, and not calling the Update method. If nothing changed in the view, EF shouldn't try to update it.

Comment: A fix that I made was just setting the items to null before inserting. It's a dumb hack, but it works in this scenario considering the user gets forwarded to a new page where the data doesn't persist anyhow. I appreciate your guys' help. @AndrewWilliamson